# Find Matching MySQL field in String Passed into Query

Tags: php, mysql, string

Here is my pseudo (fake) query of what I am trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE specific_field IS IN '{$stringPassedIn}'
```

Then on the result I want to grab the row where`specific_field` matches the string passed in.

In doing some research I found there was a lot of the opposite, for example:

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE items LIKE '%123456%'` But this is not what I am looking for - I don't believe.

Here is the real world application.  In my `php` code I extract an error message.  This error message contains a specific error code. I have a table of codes I want to compare this error string against and then return the row that includes the exact error code in the string (like in first query above).  So I am passing into the query an entire phrase.  If this is even possible or practical? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I read it three times, and still didn't really get your problem. Just imagine you would explain this to your child or parents. Use simple language, logical composed and clear structured sentences.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel I think the problem here is with you - I had no trouble grasping what the OP was asking. I certainly don't think your initial comment is justified.

Comment: @MikeW, +1 I agree, I understood the question without too much trouble.

Comment: Kudos to you. I read it a fourth time and still didn't get it (yet after having some background knowledge due to your answer). But if it's just me, then everything is fine. Please ignore me and my message.

Comment: Probably I'm just not thinking complicated enought. Y'all don't happen to be women...?

Comment: Dude. That's pretty weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse a `LIKE` predicate:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE '{$errorMessage}' LIKE CONCAT('%', errorCode, '%')
```

Think of this example, the following expression would return true:

```
'error number 12345 has occurred' LIKE '%12345%'
```

Be careful to do proper escaping on $errorMessage in case it contains special characters. Or better yet, use a prepared statement and pass the variable as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That makes total sense let me try and then I'll mark correct.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the MySQL [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_locate). You can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE LOCATE(`specificField`, '{$stringPassedIn}') is not 0
```